# How to mark as checked the checkbox if the ids is match or exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have module where I need checked the list checkbox if the ids determine that i have same ids to the another table. I have two table, Table 1 and Table 2

> Table 1 - List of Items and all items loop in the checkbox
>
> Table 2 - This table 2 are the stored ids where the user check the
> items on table and submit. and those ids where inserted to the table
> 2.

So now. If the user try to open again the checkbox list items and if one of those items is already set make the checkbox automatically checked.

I have here my loop items function:

```
    @foreach($details_items as $details_items_data)
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{$details_items_data->adi_id}}" class="form-check-input csdtc_chkbox" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">{{$details_items_data->items}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Now I have here another loop where this loop is table 2

```
   @foreach($details_set_check as $details_checker)
   @endforeach
```

Currently have the output of this.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
@foreach($details_items as $details_items_data)
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" value="{{$details_items_data->adi_id}}" class="form-check-input csdtc_chkbox" id="exampleCheck1" @foreach($details_set_check as $details_checker) {{($details_items_data->adi_id == $details_checker->id)? 'checked':''}} @endforeach>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">{{$details_items_data->items}}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make if condition.

```
<input @if(value in the lopp exists in your table) checked @endif />
```